# Ubuntu 12.04 won't shut down

Tags: kernel

I know similar questions have been asked, but I can't seem to locate and answer... so I thought I would take a stab.

However I attempt to shutdown, poweroff or restart, Ubuntu hangs on the red Ubuntu screen (with the 4 dots - the first one lights up) and it stays there.

I left it one last night and it was still there this morning.
Is this a bug? Is there a fix? Will 12.10 resolve this?

It is obvious I am not the only one dealing with it.

Thanks

Comment: try pressing the Esc key at this screen to see what it is actually doing.  Also try `sudo shutdown -P now` from a terminal.

Comment: Have the same problem. 12.04.01 64bit. Is there no other way to fix this other than shutting down with terminal ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `halt`. After several attempts, both `sudo poweroff` and `sudo halt -p` work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, and what I do is to open a Terminal (Control+Alt+t) and then I write sudo halt or sudo reboot.

Comment: Please use `sudo poweroff` and not `halt` (halt is bugged: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1019386 due to incompatible default settings if I understood it correctly).